# Can i add an online database to a Google extension

Tags: php, database, google-chrome-extension

I am making a google extension and I need a database
But I don't want it to be a local database because I cant leave it running 24/7
Is there a way to make an online database and connect to the extension?

Answer (score 0):

On https://extendsclass.com/json-storage.html, you can have an HTTP API for storing JSON files, however there is a limit of 100 KB I think. Another alternative is using https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/?p=ft&c=db&z=3, where you can use AWS to host a free NoSQL database with 25 GB of storage.

Answer (score 0):

take a look about firebase it should solve your problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).